# Unable to launch a Program using Powershell

Tags: automated-tests, tosca, beyondcompare4

I am trying to launch a program 'Beyond Compare' using the PowerShell command

```
process=Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 4\BCompare.exe"
```

This works perfectly fine when I use it in Powershell. However, the same does not work when I use Tosca.

I am using the `TBox Start Program` and passing the Argument as `$process=Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 4\BCompare.exe"`. This fails to launch the Beyond Compare program. I use Powershell to launch the program because I plan to follow up with additional arguments for file comparison.

I have tried the same syntax to launch notepad.exe and it works fine. Any reason why the Beyond Compare program is failing to launch?

Comment: you can add arguments in TBox Start Program, no need to kludge around with powershell https://documentation.tricentis.com/tosca/1600/en/content/standard_subset/automation_tools/process_operations.htm

Answer (score -1):

you would first have to define that you want to run Powershell via cmd.
https://superuser.com/questions/1080239/run-powershell-command-from-cmd.
Did you tried that?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).